# What information on a specific flight can be retrieved?

Tags: logging, website, datasets

I would like to know where and what to search in order to have information on a specific flight (i.e. scheduled departure time, real departure time, technical failures reported, etc.)

I'm guessing that this information can be found :
in the airplane's log
at the control tower (or the aeronautical uthorities)

Can you please tell me more about all this, especially the technical name of the different documents and the information contained within?

Comment: technical difficulties may not be available outside the company, only the logbook of the plane and MX would know about that, the tower only gets notified if it is an emergency

Comment: I feel this might be too broad. What are you interested in, specifically?

Comment: More specifically, i would like to know the reasons of a delay and whether these reasons were a threat to safety. is it specif enough?

Answer (score 3):

[flightradar24](http://www.flightradar24.com) takes as input mainly ADS-B data, as explained [here](http://www.flightradar24.com/how-it-works/). It seems to be enough to know scheduled departure and arrival time, departure and arrival airport, registration number and some extra pieces of data you may not need.

For technical failure, you may see the [aviation herald website](http://avherald.com/) (I don't know how to access ACARS messages)

Answer (score 2):

For historical data, I really like http://flightaware.com/. Even a GA pilot, if one requests VFR flight following, can see a history of his radar returns which can be useful as a student pilot. It also allows you to gather information on commercial flight number.